# Inspect element in Chrome by pressing a shortcut (like Q in Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, developer-tools

Firefox has a cool feature that helps easily inspect selected elements with <kbd>Q</kbd>. How to do that in Chrome?

In Firefox you move the mouse over an element, then you click the right mouse button and then Q. Very quick and convenient thing.

Is there something like this in Chrome?

Comment: Where do you press 'Q' in Firefox to inspect an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any information in the internet so I just tried every button.

It's <kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer for someone else looking for the same solution? Perhaps a screenshot or adding how to get into developer mode?